# How can I use if loop to grep a word from txt file using python?

Tags: python, linux, unix

I am currently using `if "not" or "missing" in temp_reader:`

However, it looks like it is not working. 
It always go inside of the if loop even if `not` or `missing` is not there.

How can I fix this, so that it only foes inside of the loop if a text file contains `not` or `missing`?

Comment: Please add some code that showcases your problem

Comment: what is the type of `temp_reader`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to something like this:

```
if "not" in temp_reader or "missing" in temp_reader:
```

The original condition was being parsed like this:

```
if ("not") or ("missing" in temp_reader):
```

Since `"not"` always evaluates to `True`, the branch was being taken every time.